# Connecting to a SQL server using ADODB from a C# dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, vba, ado.net, ado

I am writing a custom `Connection` class in C# for Excel to be able to connect to a SQL Server. 
When I use `SQLConnection` from `System.Data.SqlClient` library I am able to establish a connection. The working code I've got:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
    Guid("6E8B9F68-FB6C-422F-9619-3BA6D5C24E84")]
    public interface IConnection
    {
        bool Status { get; }
        bool Open();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("B280EAA4-CE11-43AD-BACD-723783BB3CF2")]
    [ProgId("Test.Connection")]
    public class Connection : IConnection
    {
        private bool status;
        private SqlConnection conn;
        private string connString = "Data Source=[server]; Initial Catalog=[initial]; User ID=[username]; Password=[password]";

        public Connection()
        {
        }

        public bool Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
        }

        public bool Open()
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                conn.Open();
                status = true;
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And after adding the reference to Excel I am able to test the connection using a simple VBA code like this:

```
Sub TestConnection()

    Dim conn As Test.Connection
    Set conn = New Test.Connection

    Debug.Print conn.Status
    conn.Open
    Debug.Print conn.Status

End Sub
```

It outputs:

> False 
>   True

So everything is fine. Now I would like to create custom `Recordset` class in my C# library so I decided to use an `ADODB` library and its `RecordSet`instead of `SqlDataReader` as I am planning to work with some big chunks of data. So, I have modified my code to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{

    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual),
    Guid("6E8B9F68-FB6C-422F-9619-3BA6D5C24E84")]
    public interface IConnection
    {
        bool Status { get; }
        bool Open();
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("B280EAA4-CE11-43AD-BACD-723783BB3CF2")]
    [ProgId("Test.Connection")]
    public class Connection : IConnection
    {

        private bool status;
        private ADODB.Connection conn = new ADODB.Connection();
        private string connString = "Data Source=[server]; Initial Catalog=[initial]; User ID=[username]; Password=[password]";

        public Connection()
        {
        }

        public bool Status
        {
            get
            {
                return status;
            }
        }

        public bool Open()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                conn.Open();
                // conn.Open(connString, ["username"], ["password"], 0)
                // what else can I try? is this where it actually fails?
                status = true;
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.ToString();
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I also have added references to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library`.

Now, when I am executing the VBA code it outputs:

> 0 
>   0

But I was expecting `0` and `1`. It seems to me like I am not properly connecting to the server *( credentials are the same i have just removed actual data from this code )*.

I have tried to use different variations of the connection string, however it always returns `0` and `0`. I have tried creating a new project with new GUIDs and also tried renaming the projects, classes, etc. nothing has worked. I am suspecting its the establishment of the connection but I am unsure how to debug a dll.

I have used [link1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308611), [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms807027.aspx), [link3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx), [link4](http://homeofcox-cs.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/use-adodbrecordset-in-c.html) for reference

**Update:**
I have wrote the exception to the file as TheKingDave suggested. This is the exception error message

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified    at ADODB._Connection.Open(String
>   ConnectionString, String UserID, String Password, Int32 Options)    at
>   TestADODB.Connection.Open() in c:\Users\administrator\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Test\Test\Connection.cs:line 49

Comment: Print out your exception to a file or something so you can see what is says. I assume that Open() is throwing an exception.

Comment: "so I decided to use an ADODB library and its RecordSet instead of SqlDataReader as I am planning to work with some big chunks of data" - not sure how you get from A to B there; ... why? You say you have some working code using `SqlClient`, but you want to use ADODB... why is that?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have been researching only for a couple of hours this morning. Let's say that my goal is to Connect to SQL Server, retrieve a RecordSet and send it to Excel for a further analysis. From what I read about SqlConnection, it is less efficient than ADODB since SqlDataReader goes line by line and ADODB is capable of providing a whole recordset. My decision was purely based on efficiency <= and also based on what I have read this morning. I may be wrong at this point as I haven't had much experience using the SqlClient library.

Comment: Does you connection string include Provider= or Driver=? I think those are necessary to tell your ADODB connection what it is connecting to.

Comment: I have been using ADODB quite frequently in VBA so I am a bit more familiar with it. However, it turns out I am having problems using it in my C# project.

Comment: @BradRem it includes [Data Source](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)=[server address];

Comment: What if you also add Provider=SQLOLEDB?

Comment: Glad it was an easy fix!

Comment: @mehow actually, I would say it is *more* efficient because of being a reader; that is still a single stream - it isn't a round-trip per row or anything. Using a reader lets you a: start consuming the data when the **first** row is available (rather than having to wait for all of them), and b: avoids having to hold all the data in memory. If you *want* a disconnected chunk-o-data, chuck it into a `DataTable` or (better, IMO) into a POCO model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection string is missing `Provider=SQLOLEDB`.

The ADODB.Connection needs to know what type of database it is connecting to.

Comment: Thank you @BradRem, well spotted!